# Querying a django model using a model name string input

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Let's say i have the following django models:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class ModelD(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

In the django ORM, i am trying to read a **string** which will be the name of a **model**, and use it to query. Something like this:

```
>>b = 'ModelB'
>>b.objects.all()
```

This will obviously not work as it is a string. I have looked at [ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes) but i am not sure how it will be helpful in my scenario. Any suggestions?

I also tried doing a `get` operation on `Contentype` like this:

```
>>> z = ContentType.objects.get(model='modelb')
>>> z
<ContentType: model b>
>>> z.__dict__
{'model': u'modelb', '_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7f195346c150>, 'id': 14, 'app_label': u'testapp'}
>>>
```

But i did not know how to proceed further from here!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're using Django < 1.7, I think you can do this.

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

z = ContentType.objects.get(model='modelb')
ModelB = get_model(z.app_label, 'ModelB')
```

For django >= 1.7, you can

```
from django.apps import apps

z = ContentType.objects.get(model='modelb')
ModelB = apps.get_model(z.app_label, 'ModelB')
```

you can then use `ModelB` to query.

Comment: `apps` is available in 1.7, actually. Also, `apps` is an object in `django.apps`, so you need `from django.apps import apps; apps.get_model(...)`.